# October CMS: How to extend the backend user with role scope

Tags: php, content-management-system, backend, octobercms

I've been able to extend the `Backend\Models\User` class and add a scoped query method to retrieve only super users:

```
public function boot()
{
    User::extend(function($model) {
        $model->addDynamicMethod('scopeIsSuperUser', function($query) {
            return $query->where('is_superuser', 1);
        });
    });
}
```

How can I have a scope method for users who are in a specific group? Like I only want users whose role is "`BookManager`". Is it possible to use the `$groups` relation already defined on the `Backend\Models\User` class?

```
public $belongsToMany = [
    'groups' => ['Backend\Models\UserGroup', 'table' => 'backend_users_groups']
];
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
User::extend(function($model) {
    $model->addDynamicMethod('scopeIsBookManager', function($query) {
        return $query->whereHas('groups', function ($query) {
            $query->where('code', 'BookManager');
        });
    });
});
```