# October CMS - get the group code of current user?

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

I need to get the group code of the current user in backend, how can I do this?

Comment: The current user might be member of multiple groups. Check the following link, it may give you a clue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47875582/69537

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to check weather user is inside of group or not and based on you need to enforce some security/rights etc..

here is the code which can be useful.

> user can have multiple `usergroup` so you will get multiple `usergroup-code` then you can check from it. (in this example we are checking user has `owners` code in his groups)

```
$user = \BackendAuth::getUser();
$currentUserGroups = $user->getGroups();
$userGroupCodes = [];

$neededCode = 'owners';

foreach ($currentUserGroups as $group) {
    $userGroupCodes[] = $group->code;
}

$hasPermission = false;
if(in_array($neededCode, $userGroupCodes)) {
    $hasPermission = true;
}

dd($hasPermission);
```

> **$hasPermission** will have the **Boolean** value now you can use it in your condition and enforce security.

Comment: I need user group for display records in my plugin.
I use this in my plugin.php boot function, and i have Error:
- Call to a member function getGroups() on null

Comment: you need to wrap it inside some relevant event  or something else because during boot Backed user is not initialized.

Comment: I created another question, you can try to answer it.
I will be very happy))
https://stackoverflow.com/q/47888265/8221154

Answer (score 2):

Shorter version of *Hardik Satasiya* code

```
$user = \BackendAuth::getUser();
$userGroupCodes = $user->getGroups()->lists('code');

$neededCode = 'owners';

$hasPermission = in_array($neededCode, $userGroupCodes);
```